# RouterOS 7, how to fair-share per interface

Tags: router, mikrotik, routeros

I'm configuring fiber for my office. Every floor is rented by someone, and I want to share the internet fairly. We've got one incoming 1Gbps fiber link, into a modem, followed by a Mikrotik router. Every floor has a port on that router.

I want to guarantee every one of the 5 floors at least 100Mbps, and then divide up the unused bandwidth. So when I'm the first to arrive in the morning, I want the full 1Gbps until others start arriving.

Pcq looks nice, but is not per port. I found https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=103164 but they simply state "Assuming that you have the appropriate packet marks in the mangle rules to identify download traffic:", which I haven't and haven't got a clue how to do.

How do I set this up?